# How to set "example" in openapi3 swagger documentation in GO

Tags: go, swagger, openapi

I am using

github.com/getkin/kin-openapi/openapi3

Can somebody tell me how to set the example value for the parameter field
`

```
swagger.Paths = openapi3.Paths{
        "/postval/subsid/{subscriberid}/updatefle": &openapi3.PathItem{
            Post: &openapi3.Operation{
                OperationID: "postvalue",
                Parameters: []*openapi3.ParameterRef{
                    {
Value: openapi3.NewPathParameter("subscriberid").WithDescription("SubscriberIdentifier").WithRequired(true).
                            WithSchema(openapi3.NewStringSchema()),
}
```

`I tried setting all the parameters, but unable to find a way to set the example

Answer (score 0):

First create the parameter, then set the example on it. Then add it
in the Path definition.

```golang
    subscriberParameter := openapi3.NewPathParameter("subscriberid").WithDescription("SubscriberIdentifier").WithRequired(true).
        WithSchema(openapi3.NewStringSchema())
    
    subscriberParameter.Example = "exampleId"
    
    swagger.Paths = openapi3.Paths{
        "/postval/subsid/{subscriberid}/updatefle": &openapi3.PathItem{
            Post: &openapi3.Operation{
                OperationID: "postvalue",
                Parameters: []*openapi3.ParameterRef{
                    {
                        Value: subscriberParameter,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```